# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}$ converge then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}$ converge then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges as well.

Can I prove this like this: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

The first equality can be done because they both converge, but I'm not sure about the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^ka_{2k}$, $s_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^ka_{2k-1}$ and $t_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^ka_k$. Then $$t_k=s_{\left\lceil\frac{k}{2}\right\rceil}+r_{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}$$

Now, since the limits
\begin{aligned}
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}s_{\left\lceil\frac{k}{2}\right\rceil}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}s_k\\
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}r_{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}r_k
\end{aligned}
exist and are finite (the series converge), so too does the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}t_k$.